# change z-index of a div after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, settimeout

I need a div to fade in instantly and fade out after six seconds... (using the code below i have that part working)

I also need the z-index of the div to change, so that I may access the content under it once it fades out...

im not sure if changing the `z-index` is the best way to go about this, but after 6 seconds i pretty much want it to be as if the div never faded in in the first place, like the code for the div was never there...

How would I go about doing this?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #overlay{
        display:none;
        background:#CD2026;
        width: 508px;
        height: 649px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:12px;
        top:0px;
        z-index:100;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(6000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    //]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $("#overlay").css('z-index','100');
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#overlay").css('z-index','-100'); },6000)
    });
    //]]>
</script>

<div id="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: When your element get `fadeOut`, its `display` became `none`, so it isn't on the page anymore, there is no need to set `z-index` for it to access elements behind it, it already disappeard completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off setting the display to none instead of changing the z-index if you want it to be 'like the code for the div was never there...'

change your fadeOut to:

```
.fadeOut('slow', function(){$(this).css('display', 'none')})
```

otherwise, if you still want to change z-index, change your fadeOut to:

```
.fadeOut('slow', function(){$(this).css('z-index', '-100')})
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbJZs/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, I figured out what was causing it not to let me interact with the elements behind it. Your code helped me, Thank you for taking the time out to help me, I appreciate it!

Comment: @JStormThaKid no worries. Just to add, this changes the z-index/display after the fadeOut finishes, instead of timing the change to coincide with the expected end of the fadeOut

Comment: yea, heres what i finally used and it works... `$(window).load(function(){
$('#productOverlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(6000).fadeOut('slow', function(){$(this).css('z-index', '-100')})
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity:0,'z-index':-100},6000);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Rohan, tried your code but it doesn't seem to give me access to the content underneath... even after the fade out... and with your code, it doesn't fade out, just cuts...

Comment: i have altered it to still fade out like so... ' $('#productOverlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(6000).fadeOut('slow').animate({opacity:1,'z-index':-100}); ' but still no cigars...

Comment: @JStormThaKid Don't use any other code, just use the above I have made changes.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, I figured out what was causing it not to let me interact with the elements behind it. Your code helped me, Thank you for taking the time out to help me, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change this line. Adding {} in values.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#overlay").css({'z-index','-100'}); },6000)
```

Correct Answer :

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(6000).fadeOut('slow')});

  window.setTimeout(function(){ 
      $("#overlay").css({'z-index':'-100'});
  },6000);
```

This works

Comment: When you say Adding {} in values... you mean... setTimeout(function(){ $("#overlay").css('z-index','-100'); },**{6000}**)?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati No you don't put `{}` around `'z-index','-100'`. Its not an object. Correct code with `{}` would be `.css({'z-index': '-100'});` Notice the `:` instead of `,` although `setTimeout(function(){ $("#overlay").css('z-index','-100'); },6000);` is correct

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati - Awesome! Thanks for your help, I figured out what was causing it not to let me interact with the elements behind it. Your code helped me, Thank you for taking the time out to help me, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKezP/1/)

You can remove `$(document).ready();` and just keep the code inside it if you place this at the end of the HTML file just before `</body>`

The button under the div is clickable after 6 sec when the div fades out

#### Edit

You don't need to change `z-index` as `.fadeOut()` sets `display: none`. The div doesn't interfere with the page anymore

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, I figured out what was causing it not to let me interact with the elements behind it. Your code helped me, Thank you for taking the time out to help me, I appreciate it!